# Number of Binary Search Trees of a given Height

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

How can I find the number of BSTs upto a given height h and discard all the BSTs with height greater than h for a given set of unique numbers?

I have worked out the code using a recursive approach

```
static int bst(int h,int n){
    if(h==0&&n==0)return 1;
    else if(h==0&&n==1)return 1;
    else if(h==0&&n>1)return 0;
    else if(h>0&&n==0)return 1;
    else{
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
            sum+=bst(h-1,i-1)*bst(h-1,n-i);
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dynamic programming, as always.

Comment: I know how to calculate the total number of bsts that are formed with n number of nodes using dynamic programming. But what if we have to restrict the tree height to a particular number.

Comment: For example, for 4 nodes the number of bsts are 14. But what of we want to restrict the tree height to 3. The number of trees will be less now.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat can you explain it?

Comment: Index the table by height and number of nodes.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat i have worked out the code using a recursive approach which is quite slow.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat i dont have much experience in dynamic programming.can you suggest the appropriate changes?and what will be index of the memo.

Comment: @AmanArora May i suggest a code in C.

Comment: @Sumeet yes sure.it would be of great help.

Comment: @AmanArora But it uses recursion and u said it is slow?

Comment: @Sumeet yes it is. the running time is exponential due to so many recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can speed it up by adding memoization as @DavidEisenstat suggested in the comments.

You create a memoization table to store the values of already computed results.
In the example, `-1` indicates the value has not been computed yet.

Example in c++

```
long long memo[MAX_H][MAX_N];

long long bst(int h,int n){
    if(memo[h][n] == -1){
        memo[h][n] = //Compute the value here using recursion
    }
    return memo[h][n];
}

...

int main(){
    memset(memo,-1,sizeof memo);
    bst(102,89);
}
```

This will execute in `O(h*n)` as you will only compute `bst` once for each possible pair of `n` and `h`. Another advantage of this technique is that once the table is filled up, bst will respond in O(1) (for the values in the range of the table). 
Be careful not to call the function with values above `MAX_H` and `MAN_N`. Also keep in mind memoization is a memory-time tradeoff, meaning your program will run faster, but it will use more memory too.

More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization